# Generic Pagination in ZF2

Tags: php, pagination, zend-framework2

**EDIT** My question is how to make pagination on **View** generic, currently what i have to do is some what like this on every page where i need pagination variables set

```
  <?php echo ( count($this->paginator) > 0 ) ? $this->paginationControl($this->paginator, 'Sliding', 'administration/pager.phtml', array('url' => $this->url('company'))) : ""; ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dear which you want to do is clearly mentioned in zf2 documentation:
    http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/tutorials/tutorial.pagination.html
"Let’s create the partail in the module/Application/view/partial/ folder, so that we can use the control in all our modules:" 
Above mention line shows that if we want to make pagination generic which will be available for all module, then make it partial in Application module.